# Firebase for a cli login

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express

I want to create a cli in order to create commands to control a website's carousel. But to do that i want to use firebase for login but i don't want to make the user login everytime they run a cli command like start i want to run a command like login and to login them in firebase so when firebase is initialized the next time they don't need to sign in again. In web apps or phone apps it works because the account is remebembered but in a node js server even if i login, the account is never remebered, so `firebase.onAuthStateChanged` always returns `null`.
This is what happens on start:

```
    app.listen(5100, () => {
    console.log("The slid server has already starterd");
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        console.log(user);
    })
    opn("http://localhost:5100");
```

and the user is always `null`. So how can i remember the user with firebase in a node js cli?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, it's from [Firebase Official Auth Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth)

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  }
});
```

In your scenario:

```
app.listen(5100, () => {
  console.log("The slid server has already starterd");
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if(user){
    console.log(user);
    }
  });
});
opn("http://localhost:5100");
```

Comment: I have already done this. firebase.onAuthStateChanged would not work without initializing.

Comment: What do you see in Firebase Authentication? is the value being saved there? i.e identifier and User UID?

Comment: Are you registering your user with firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword()?

Comment: No. the function returns null. If i run the server with firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword the functions returns all the data needed. And then if i run the server again without firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword the onAuthStateChanged returns null.

Comment: Try to do the following steps: 1. Do the steps(firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword ) in which you get all the data, then check your firebase console Authentication, check if the data is being stored or not. 2. Run the server again(when your data is null), check your firebase console again, if it's not being stored in the Authentication, maybe that can be the issue.